# Trying to add javascript using itext for adding elements

Tags: javascript, adobe, itext

I am trying to add elements such as 'cost A', 'Cost B' into 'Total'.
I want to add this as a JavaScript into my PDF using iText (using pdf stamper).

I tried two ways but neither worked.

1. ```
   stamper.addJavaScript(
   "var arr = new Array('costA', 'costB');"+
                        "var nameField = this.getField('Total);" +
                        "nameField.setAction('Calculate',‘AFSimple_Calculate('SUM',arr)’)");
   ```
2. ```
   stamper.addJavaScript("this.getField(Total).value  =  (this.getField('costA').value + this.getField('costB').value)");
   ```

This is my first post on SO.. please forgive me if I am not clear.....

It is working now :

I followed the syntax given in adobe JavaScript strictly and used double quotes where mentioned instead of single quotes.....and it worked...

```
 stamper.addJavaScript(
                    "var nameField = this.getField('Total');" +
                    "nameField.setAction(\"Calculate\",'AFSimple_Calculate(\"SUM\",new Array(\"costA\", \"costB\"))')");
```

**Adobe Example** :

```
f.setAction("Calculate",
'AFSimple_Calculate("SUM",
new Array ("line.1",
"line.3"))' );
```

Comment: I think you missed quotes `'`in Total. Also how do you manage to type `‘` `’` with your keyboard? Better type it correctly with your keyboard and not copy/paste!

Comment: I tried those corrections.....but did not work......

Comment: Re-edit your post with the string correction. Either there is syntax error in your script or iText do not support it or you didn't follow the documentation correctly.

Comment: Thanks....I referred to adobe document....edited my post.....it was single quotes which caused the confusion...thanks